# Can I print the partial definition of not finished proof in coq?

Tags: coq

Is there any command to print the not finished proof with metavariables?

For example,

```
Lemma a: forall P Q, (P -> Q) -> P -> Q.
intros.
apply X.
```

in this state of proof, can I print `a := X ?` by a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Show Proof` command. On your example it prints the following.

```
(fun (P Q : Type) (X : P -> Q) (X0 : P) => X ?Goal)
```